# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a method below that is supposed to return an **ArrayList** of **Event** objects. I am using the method of mapping the data stored in firebase to a **POJO**. From the debugging, the mapping is correct and I am adding the objects to the **ArrayList jsonString**, the code is crashing upon exiting the for loop.

It gives error:
`com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap`.

I didn't add a lot of code because this method is independent .

```
public ArrayList<Event> getJsonString(){
  final ArrayList<Event> jsonString = new ArrayList();

  mFirebaseDatabaseReference = database.getInstance().getReference(MESSAGES_CHILD);
  //mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD);
  mFirebaseDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for(DataSnapshot eventSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        Event event = eventSnapshot.getValue(Event.class);
        jsonString.add(event);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
  });

   return jsonString;
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
07-25 21:21:23.178 3037-3079/com.firstintel.zimnights E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.firstintel.zimnights-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.firstintel.zimnights-1/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
07-25 21:21:23.191 3037-3079/com.firstintel.zimnights E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.firstintel.zimnights-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.firstintel.zimnights-1/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
07-25 21:21:27.313 3037-3095/com.firstintel.zimnights E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f758c234b90
07-25 21:21:27.415 3037-3095/com.firstintel.zimnights E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f758c235530
07-25 21:21:28.228 3037-3037/com.firstintel.zimnights E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.firstintel.zimnights, PID: 3037
                                                                        com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.firstintel.zimnights.EventFragment$1.onDataChange(EventFragment.java:146)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagp.zzSu(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzags$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: You must show the complete exception stack trace and identify the line in your code that causes the exception to be thrown.  [edit] your post and include the necessary information.  Also, this code doesn't really do anything.  You set a listener but then didn't invoke any other methods so you will return an empty list.

Comment: Noted  thanks I have added the stacktrace

Comment: You should also post the code for your POJO `Event`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Managed to do a workaround , instead of returning the ArrayList, I just called the adapter in my ***getJsonString()*** which I then called in the ***OnCreate()***. Voila works perfect will figure out which Design pattern that is , Anyone knows it?

Answer (score -1):

fixed many case by checking variable names and their order even with ArrayList in class but stacked similar case the difference is one has array one has pushed key valued list.